# Make python remember what player picks and changes game depending on answer

Tags: python

the question i have sounds complicated but i'm sure its simple. i want my code to remember if the player is male or female and take them down different paths. so males have one story and females have another.

```
while True:
    sex = raw_input ("> ")
    if sex.lower() not in ('male', 'female'):
        print("What? Try again")
        continue
    else:
        break
if sex.lower() == "male":
    print("'Okay Mr %s get ready for the test, it won't be easy'")% name
elif sex.lower() == "female":
    print("'Well Ms %s i hope youre ready for the test'")% name
```

Comment: What is the problem? As far as I can tell, your code should work as intended.

Comment: Um, the variable `sex` already "remembers" this information. What more are you looking for?

Comment: @murgatroid99 well after this part of code i want it to males go one way and females go another. if that makes any sense i might be wording it terribly wrong

Comment: @chepner but how do i continue on and make male and female have seperate stories?

Comment: You check the value of `sex` each time you need to do something different, just like you did in the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
def male_questions():
    # all the questions for men

def female_questions():
    # all the questions for women

while True:
    sex = raw_input ("> ")
    if sex.lower() not in ('male', 'female'):
        print("What? Try again")
        continue
    else:
        break
if sex.lower() == "male":
    print("'Okay Mr %s get ready for the test, it won't be easy'")% name
    male_questions()
elif sex.lower() == "female":
    print("'Well Ms %s i hope youre ready for the test'")% name
    female_questions()
```

Note that this is a poor implementation of a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). The link may be able to help you build a much (MUCH) better one.

Also possible (without a state machine) if all you need to do is vary the question:

```
class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, male_q, female_q):
        """Question("Do you have a beard? ", "Purses or wallets? ")"""
        self.male = male_q
        self.female = female_q

questions = [Question("foo","bar"), Questions("spam","eggs"), ...]

for num,question in enumerate(questions, 1):
    print("{}. {}".format(num, question.__dict__.get(sex, "male")))
```

Comment: ah okay. thanks one of these two will definitely work.